# Getting an XML element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

In the following program, `helloElem` is not null, as expected.

```
string xml = @"<root>
<hello></hello>
</root>";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var helloElem = xmlDoc.Root.Element("hello"); //not null
```

If give the XML a namespace:

```
string xml = @"<root xmlns=""namespace"">
<hello></hello>
</root>";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var helloElem = xmlDoc.Root.Element("hello"); //null
```

why does `helloElem` become null? How do I get the hello element in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do as below

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace  ns = xmlDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var helloElem = xmlDoc.Root.Element(ns+ "hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

Surely you can get rid of `namespaces`, see below:

```
string xml = @"<root>
                   <hello></hello>
               </root>";

 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 var helloElem = xmlDoc.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == "hello");
```

Above code could handle nodes with or without `namespaces`. See ***[Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx)*** for more information. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 XNamespace ns = "namespace";
 var helloElem = xmlDoc.Root.Element(ns + "hello");
```

Comment: That works, but is it possible to make the code support all cases, with/without namespaces and not hardcoding the namespace?

Comment: @roger.james That's like asking the C# compiler to ignore namespaces and just try to find the matching object in your project. Just like your projects, namespaces in XML help to differentiate a `candy:bar` from a `foo:bar` which are surely two very different things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a default namespace XPath.

```
private static XElement XPathSelectElementDefaultNamespace(XDocument document,
                                                           string element)
{
    XElement result;
    string xpath;

    var ns = document.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().ToString();

    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ns))
    {
        xpath = string.Format("//{0}", element);
        result = document.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
    }
    else
    {
        var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsManager.AddNamespace(ns, ns);

        xpath = string.Format("//{0}:{1}", ns, element);
        result = document.XPathSelectElement(xpath, nsManager);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
string xml1 = @"<root>
<hello></hello>
</root>";

string xml2 = @"<root xmlns=""namespace"">
<hello></hello>
</root>";

var d = XDocument.Parse(xml1);
Console.WriteLine(XPathSelectElementDefaultNamespace(d, "hello"));
// Prints: <hello></hello>

d = XDocument.Parse(xml2);
Console.WriteLine(XPathSelectElementDefaultNamespace(d, "hello"));
// Prints: <hello xmlns="namespace"></hello>
```